# Javascript animate CSS float property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a class added via JavaScript which makes a section float right and for this section class I want to animate the floating into it's position, however I have not found anyway to make this work. Is there a way to use css3 to animate floating?

Comment: No. You need to use javascript.

Comment: I think it will be something like that in jQuery      $(selector).animate({float:'right'}, yourSpeedHere);
not sure ;) Check the manual of animate :)

Comment: @Mr.TK nope — jQuery's animate, like CSS transitions and animations, can only animate property values that are on a spectrum, like colours or numeric values.

Comment: `float` alters the layout model, there is no intermediate state between `float:none` and `float:left/right` to be animated! jQuery only animates numeric properties (and colors with either jQuey Color or jQuery UI plugin included).

Comment: Thats true... Damn... Try reading current position of object to float, clone it, hide clone and insert it after object, set (float: right) for clone, read clone position in px, set object position to "X" px with animate, after animate remove clone and set object float: to right. :D  LULz :D

Answer (score 4):

It isn't possible using CSS alone for the reason's stated above. But check out Darcy Clark's answer on this post:

http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-in-jquery-to-animate-an-element-from-a-float-right-position-to-a-float-left-position

He links to this fiddle and seems to have figured it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/darcyclarke/m9pTN/

HTML

```
<div class="float right"></div>
<div class="float left"></div>
```

CSS

```
.float {
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left; 
    clear: both;
}

.left {
    background: blue;
    float: right;  
}
```

JS

```
(function(){
    var $plugin = jQuery.sub();
    $plugin.fn.animate = function(props, speed, cb){
        if(typeof(speed) == "function")
            cb = speed, speed = 500;
        if(typeof(cb) != "function")
            cb = function(){};
        return $.each(this, function(i, el){
            el = $(el);
            if(props.float && props.float != el.css("float")){
                var elem = el.clone().css(props).insertBefore(el),
                    temp = (props.float == el.css("float")) ? elem.position().left : el.position().left;
                props.marginLeft = elem.position().left;
                elem.remove();
                el.css({float:"left",marginLeft:temp});
            }
            $(this).animate(props, speed, function(){
                $(this).css(props);
                cb();
            });
        });
    };

    $(".float.right").bind("click", function(){
        $plugin(this).animate({float:"right"}, 1000); 
    });

    $(".float.left").bind("click", function(){
        $plugin(this).animate({float:"left"}, 1000); 
    });

})();
```

I can't speak to whether or not doing this is actually a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS:

```
.float{
   position: absolute;
   right:0;
   transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

You can also use

```
transform: translateX(100%);
transition: all 300ms ease;
```

You'll have to add the vendor prefixes for transform and transition though. No JQuery needed and the answers above are not correct.

Comment: Are you sure you know what he means by float?

Comment: I guess he wants to have things positioned to the right on the screen instead of center or left. The right property in CSS does just that.

Comment: There's a bunch of differences between absolute an float.

Comment: Sure, but imagine having those features (like clearing text etc) active during a transition. If you move an object from the middle of the screen to the right and then apply float right to it you will get it all. right? With JQuery it would be something like this: $('#element).animate({'right' : 0}, 300).css({float: 'right'});

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about animating float property, you can write transition on flex container.

Create a flex container like below:

```
<div class="main-div" style="display:flex; transition: width 2s">
   <div id="child1" style="order: 1 width: 10%"></div>
   <div id="child2" style="order: 2"></div>
   <div id="child3" style="order: 3"></div>
</div>
<button>Change width of child1</button>

<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function(){
      $('#child1').width(100%);
      $('#child3').hide(1000);
  });
});
</script>
```

Now apply animation property on width change of div.order1. Hide div.order3 and change div.order1 width to 100% via javascript.

You will get your desired animation.

*** code above is not checked. I have just written it. So, please modify it according your requirement.