# Animate a floating element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of elements that :

```
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
  <li>Element 4</li>
  <li>Element 5</li>
  <li>Element 6</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS for these are :

```
display: inline-block;
width: 45px;
height: 45px;
```

Then the ul tag is :

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

`onClick` I add a class which floats the element left. So they're all in a row. `onClick` whatever element I select floats to the left (first in the row).

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('left_align');
});
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37naqebd/)

How do I get it so it moves the other elements and scrolls across kind of animated.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this [stackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235894/javascript-animate-css-float-property)

Answer (score 5):

> There are several properties or values you’ll want to transition, but which are not supported by browsers. [List of animatable CSS properties](http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/)

`float` is not a `css3` animatable property.

You can try this patch:

```js
    $('li').on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('left_align');
    });
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: red;
  transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
}
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.left_align {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -5px;
  background: yellow;
  transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
  <li>Element 4</li>
  <li>Element 5</li>
  <li>Element 6</li>
</ul>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/37naqebd/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use CSS to animate float properties.
The following SO post has an interesting solution to your problem:
[Javascript animate CSS float property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235894/javascript-animate-css-float-property)

If you still want to animate and not use floats, you can try using a solution employing margins. To fix the problem of spacing between list elements, you can just animate to negative margin values.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: red;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
li:first-of-type {
   margin-left: 0;
}
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.left_align {
  margin-left: -4px;;
  background: yellow;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/37naqebd/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found to do this in jQuery is to reorder the elements and adjust their 'left' css values (you do have to remove the floats from the li elements since transitions wont work with floats):

```
   var lefts = [0,50,100,150,200,250]
   for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        $('li:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').css('left', lefts[i]);
   }

   $('li').on('click', function() {
        // reorder clicked element to move it to the top of the list
        $(this).insertBefore($('li:nth-child(1)')); 

        //update element left values
        for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
            $('li:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').css('left', lefts[i]);
        }
   });
```

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsheridan390/37naqebd/7/).