# CSS transition while moving image to different div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to move an image from one div to another. And then use the transition property by CSS to make it look good. Here is what I tried:

```js
var image = document.getElementById('some-image');

image.addEventListener("click", function() {
 document.getElementById('image-holder2').appendChild(image);
});
```

```css
div#image-holder1 {
  float: left;
}

div#image-holder2 {
  float: right;
}

img {
  max-width: 50px;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.85, 0.17, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="image-holder1">
  <img id="some-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/1200px-Solid_blue.svg.png">
</div>
<div id="image-holder2">
  
</div>
```

As you can see, there is no transition; How can I make the image go to the position smoothly instead of "teleporting"?

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32253766/5605822

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript animate CSS float property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235894/javascript-animate-css-float-property)

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify `cubic-bezier` inside transaction.

Hope this helps

Good [source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_cubic-bezier.asp)

```js
var image = document.getElementById('some-image');

image.addEventListener("click", function() {
 document.getElementById('image-holder2').appendChild(image);
});
```

```css
div#image-holder1 {
  float: left;
}

div#image-holder2 {
  float: right;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  transition: width 2s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.7, 1.0, 0.1);
}

img:hover{
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-holder1">
  <img id="some-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/1200px-Solid_blue.svg.png">
</div>
<div id="image-holder2">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs a small trick, First just translate your current element and don't append this until transition completes. In hurry I don't use the exact calculation, 
But I advice you not to use left 90.4%, instead of this, use 100%-Image-Width

```js
var image = document.getElementById('some-image');

image.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('image-holder1').classList.add('moveNow');
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('image-holder2').appendChild(image);
  },1000);
});
```

```css
div#image-holder1 {
}
.parent {display: flex; justify-content:space-between;}
img {
  max-width: 50px;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.85, 0.17, 1, 1);
}
#image-holder1 {
  transition: left 1s;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
#image-holder1.moveNow {
  left: 90.4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div id="image-holder1">
  <img id="some-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/1200px-Solid_blue.svg.png">
</div>
<div id="image-holder2">
</div>
</div>
```